# How to change data produced by CKEditor dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, richtextbox

I want to do some stuff with the image that is added using Image toolbar button in CKEditor. 
I actually want to get the url and modify if required.

How can I do it?

I am able to do that stuff using `dataFilter` but only when image is directly *pasted* into the
editor. But `dataFilter` rule doesn't execute when image is added using default Image button in editor.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'idContent' );

CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( e ) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.idContent.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
            "img": function (element) {
                var imageSrcUrl = element.attributes.src;    
                // Do some stuffs here.     
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved my purpose using following code

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data
    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
        dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        var onOk = dialogDefinition.onOk;

        dialogDefinition.onOk = function( e ) {
            var input = this.getContentElement( 'info', 'txtUrl' ),
                imageSrcUrl = input.getValue();

            //! Manipulate imageSrcUrl and set it 
            input.setValue( imageSrcUrl );

            onOk && onOk.apply( this, e );  
        };
    }
});
```